# Where does the tune for birkat hamazon come from?

Tags: history, music, bentching, provenance

It's hard to describe who's tune this is and I can only refer to it as the 'commonly used' or 'popular' tune for birkat hamazon. It seems like it is compiled of many unrelated tunes. At times there are melodies for a specific phrase and at other times there are melodies for paragraphs.

Was there an 'original tune' that has now developed and where was it from?

[I'm interested in this, because I dislike the melodies (!) and of course wish to implement universal changes at some very near future.]

Comment: this one? http://youtu.be/D-EhExbPqTc?t=37s

Comment: There are different tunes in different places. For instance, Brits and Americans with similar backgrounds have different tunes.

Comment: Just curious - how exactly does one go about implementing universal changes?

Comment: @Dave I haven't decided yet, but probably via the blessings of totalitarianism in the form of force and social engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard (but never confirmed) that it was composed by [Rabbi Manis Mandel](http://www.imamother.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=122427#122427) a"h, the longtime Menahel of Yeshiva of Brooklyn.

UPDATE: It seems that this information is at least partially incorrect, as the first part of the tune was apparently composed by [Moshe Nathanson](http://archive.chazzanut.com/hanashir/msg04217.html) (of "Hava Nagila" fame).

Comment: This may have been the case originally, however, the tune is varied and haphazard at times. It doesn't make sense for someone to compose it in this way. In which case, who compiled the tunes and placed them in different places? I could be wrong!

Comment: I assumed that it was originally composed this way, as a hybrid song / chant, to make it more interesting for the kids to sing. Judging by the tune's wide popularity and appeal over the last half century, I'd say it was quite successful in that regard!

Comment: Just to avoid a misconception - the tune of Hava Nagila is a chassidic melody (still song in skver i have heard) and the words were added much later. learn more about the song here http://www.myjewishlearning.com/culture/2/Music/Israeli_Music/Folk_Music/Hava_Nagila.shtml?p=1

Answer (score 6):

Most of the tunes still used were written by Moshe Nathanson in 1938 (some say 1939) for Camp Ramah, a Conservative Jewish overnight camp. He published the sheet music in "Shirei Manginoth", and here is a recording of him performing it.

https://youtu.be/rGkUwZdwoRY

The irony is that Nathanson was the cantor at the Society for the Advancement of Judaism at the time, the flagship synagogue of Reconstructionist Judaism, where Mordecai Kaplan was rabbi. This is a movement which at the time taught that "God is the sum of all natural processes that allow man to become self-fulfilled." Atheism, according to halakhah, and by the standards of the other movements.

So we are thanking G-d using the tunes of someone who broke away from classical Judaism over a disbelief in what we call G-d.

Comment: So what your saying is might as well use Debbie Friedman's Havdala tune?

Comment: @user6591 : I think her tune is easier to defend using, because it's at least written by someone who believes in G-d and in some form of Havdalah.

Comment: True point. Which makes it more interesting. Btw, based on the description, I think they would qualify more as pantheistic than atheistic.

Comment: @user6591: First, I think panentheism would halachically be considered atheism. But in any case, I am not sure you are correct. A "God" which is the process by which man seeks holiness isn't "G-d" is even further from theism than pantheism is. And doesn't remotely resemble any traditional use of the word.

Comment: @user6591 -- looking at last April's comment: I meant "pantheism", not "panentheism". Pantheism, equating God and the universe is much like atheism. But panentheism, saying the universe is of G-d, but that G-d is "more than" the universe, still asserts something beyond the universe. Unlike atheism.

Comment: I figured that's what you meant as you worded it correctly the second time. I wasn't making that point halachikaly, more technically as far as terminology goes. But I actually didn't understand what you meant with you sentence starting "A "God" etc".

Comment: @user6591: Mordechai Kaplan defined God as the process by which man seeks holiness. That's just reusing the word to mean something entirely different in order to hide the fact that his formulation of Reconstructionist Judaism had no deity. What it had was something else, this "process", which he felt could play the same role. Kaplan coined the word "transvalue" to describe this taking a word, leaving its surrounding concept, but giving it a new meaning that serves a parallel role.  That's about all the Reconstructionism I want to waste time explaining. Let's talk Torah instead.

Comment: Got it. On to Torah indeed!:)

Answer (score 4):

The common melody for הזן את העולם was indeed written by Moshe Nathanson. There exists a pamphlet containing all his melodies for Bentching, many of which are not in use.

It is worth noting, however, that the general nusach, which comprises most of its modern rendition, is largely traditional to Yekkes and other Central-European communities (Oberlanders, etc.). According to Cantor Isaak Lachmann in Hürben the Bentching was chanted according to a melody quite similar to the current. A very similar melody was used in Hungary in 1898 according to Cantor Mayer Wodak and in Berlin in 1902 according to Cantor Aron Friedmann.

This nusach differs significantly from the traditional Eastern-European nusach for Bentching which is still common amongst Chasidim.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and welcome to Mi Yodeya. +1

Answer (score 0):

I could confirm it better, but based on what my grandfather שיחי told me, there was a small group of Viennese Bochurim (my Grandpa is from Vienna too) that started a small camp in Brooklyn - this was in the early '50 - and they would do Bentching with the tune they have been taught in Vienna. This was one of the first Orthodox camps in the US, and the tune just caught up becoming 'universal'...

Comment: welcome to the site. thanks for the contribution.

Comment: could zalmen please find out from his grandfather which camp he is referring to? Was it Camp Agudah (not in Brooklyn, but in Highmount and later Ferndale)?